# How to pass Array of Js functions to another Js function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am newbie to java script. I am writing some asynchronous functions  let's say `func1, func2, func3`. But they have to execute one after another. So i decided to use `async` lib to execute one after another.

**SCRIPT FILE:**

```
 function func1(param1,param2){
  //dosomething ..
 }
 function func2(param3,param4){
  //dosomething ..
 }
 function func3(param5,param6){
  //dosomething ..
 }
 function myfunction(arr){
   console.log(arr);
   async.series(arr,function(){
      //do something ..
 });
 }
```

**HTML FILE:**

```
<a onclick="myfunction([func1('p1','p2'),func2('p3','p4'),func('p5','p6')])"></a>
```

But when i try `console.log`, it is giving `null,null,null`

kindly provide me some solution regarding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not passing an array of function references, you're passing an array of the **result** of **calling** those functions. The array will contain whatever those functions returned (or `undefined` if they don't return anything).

If you want to create a function reference with arguments "baked in", you can do that with `Function#bind`:

```
myFunction([func1.bind(null, 'p1','p2'), ...])
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^
```

`Function#bind` creates a new function that, when called, will call the original with a given `this` value (I've used `null` above on the assumption `this` isn't important) and the arguments you give `bind` (followed by any arguments the new function is called with).

Example:

```js
myfunction([
  func1.bind(null, 'p1', 'p2'),
  func1.bind(null, 'p3', 'p4'),
  func1.bind(null, 'p5', 'p6')
]);
function func1(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log("func1 got (" + arg1 + "," + arg2 + ")");
}
function myfunction(functions) {
  functions.forEach(function(f) {
    f();
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi T.J. Crowder, Thanks for the reply ,i will try this one

Comment: In this context, when you say "followed by any arguments the new function is called with" where would those arguments be added to the above code, and would those arguments also be passed to the original function or are they just used in the new function?

Comment: @Dellirium: If you do `var f = foo.bind(null, 1, 2);` then `f(3, 4);`, `foo` gets called with the arguments `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. E.g.: The ones from the `bind`, followed by any provided when calling the bound function. (And `this` in the call to `foo` will either be `null` [in strict mode] or the global object [in loose mode].)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, one last question, if in this case we were to use `foo.bind(null)` and then `f(1,2)` would the `foo` get called with 1 and 2? I know it obliterates the point of the bind, but i'm curious.

Comment: @Dellirium: Yes, it would. That doesn't obliterate the purpose of the bind, because it still sets a specific `this`, it just doesn't affect the arguments. `bind` is *primarily* used for setting `this`, in fact.